# Transformar Set<Integer> em Set<String>

Tags: java, android

Preciso armazenar um `Set<Integer>` dentro de um sharedpreferences, porém ele só aceita `Set<String>`, tem como fazer essa conversão ?

```
            Set<Integer> checados = group.getCheckedIds();
            prefeditor.putStringSet("cardio_dias", checados); <- So aceita Set<String> aqui
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode simplesmente usar um laço/ciclo que passe em todos os elementos e os converta um a um para o tipo que pretende, criando assim um novo `Set` desse tipo. A conversão para `String` é feita chamando o `toString()` e de volta para inteiro faz com `Integer.parseInt()`.

**Guardar o `Set`**

```
Set<Integer> ints = new HashSet<>(); //o seu Set

Set<String> intsEmString = new HashSet<>();
for (Integer i : ints){
    intsEmString.add(i.toString()); //guardar a representação em String de cada um
}

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putStringSet("meu_set", intsEmString); //guardar o novo Set<String>
editor.commit();
```

**Ler o `Set`**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//ler o Set<String> guardado
Set<String> intsEmString = sharedPref.getStringSet("meu_set", null); 
Set<Integer> ints = new HashSet<>(); //criar o novo que vai receber os valores

if (intsEmString != null){
    for(String s : intsEmString){
        ints.add(Integer.parseInt(s)); //converter de volta cada um com parseInt
    }
}

//utilizar o Set<Integer> restaurado
```

Answer (score 4):

Com o java8, você pode utilizar o stream:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Set<Integer> checados = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> checadosString = checados.stream().map(inteiro -> inteiro.toString()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ou no lugar da seta, `Integer::toString`

Comment: Eu tentei usar dessa forma, mas o compilador reclama que o método é ambíguo: Ambiguous method reference: both toString() and toString(int) from the type Integer are eligible

Comment: tem razão, lembrei agora que passei pela mesma situação no trabalho e tive de ir para essa solução com a seta...

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> checadosStrings = new HashSet<String>();
for (Integer checado : checados) {
    checadosStrings.add(checado.toString());
}
```

Comment: Poderia deixar explícito onde sua resposta difere da do Isac? Não vi nenhum acréscimo em sua resposta, sem falar que ela não explica nada, apenas exibe um código que funciona